What the relation between extensions and layers in Vulkan?
It's not quite clear to me about the relation and differences between extensions and layers in Vulkan.
From my perspective, a layer is a mechanism that intercepts Vulkan API calls, forming a chain from the application down to the ICD, where each layer performs its function sequentially. Extensions, on the other hand, offer additional capabilities that enhance Vulkan's functionality.
What puzzles me is the necessity of specifying a layer when enumerating or querying extension information. For instance:
VkResult vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
    const char* pLayerName,
    uint32_t* pPropertyCount,
    VkExtensionProperties* pProperties);

This implies that extensions are provided by layers, complicating the concept of a layer from being simply an interceptor of function calls to also being a 'module' that supplies extra functionalities.
This means that to activate an extension, I must first identify and enable the layer that provides it, rather than just activating the extension itself without concerning myself with its layer.

Layers have the option to provide extensions so that the application can communicate with them. For instance, the Discord overlay layer could offer an extension that could control whether the Discord overlay is visible.
In practice, I don't think any common layers actually provide an extension. If you're are expecting a specific layer to be present, and you know what extensions that layer typically provides, you can call vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties to validate that they're present before activating them. If you're just doing graphics stuff without regard for any extra layers, you'll probably never need to do this.

This means that to activate an extension, I must first identify and enable the layer that provides it, rather than just activating the extension itself without concerning myself with its layer.

Yes, you must always validate an extension is present before activating it. That is why vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties exists. But most extensions are provided by the Vulkan loader or the driver, rather than by a layer.

VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_synchronization2 provides the synchronization2 functionality implemented in terms of the 1.0 synchronization primitives if the underlying driver doesn't provide it.  Same with VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_shader_object and VK_EXT_shader_object.
